# Error on QGIS r.reclass for Mac and Windows

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am currently trying to use r.reclass from QGIS on Mac computer.

However, if I run r.reclass it keeps getting error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 428, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 389, in executeGrass
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 11: illegal multibyte sequence
Execution failed after 0.48 seconds
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_173310bd80834b78955ec77e270757ff/cdd1a6c9e96240d48b22fea90a31393b/output.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.**
```

I tried using another computer to solve this problem but it seems it's not working on both Mac and Windows computers.

I wonder whether I HAVE DONE something wrongly? or it this a bug error??

Comment: c:/progr.. implies Windows platform.  You'll need to change paths in your code to run on a Mac I think